# How to force mobile browsers to reload the page when the application is reopened

Tags: javascript, php, html

As you may know, in chrome or firefox mobile, when you are visiting a webpage, if you close the browser and then open again, the first thing the app does is to open that webpage again, but it opens the version you left when you closed, so, for example if you're watching a forum thread with 4 posts and close, the next time you open you see the same thread with the same 4 posts even if there were new posts, the only way you can know is reloading the page.

I'm facing issues because my session variables expires but the page in a previous version is opened and then I get loads of notices due to the session variables not being defined.

I need to find a way to force the mobile browser to open a fresh instance of my page, so if the session variables already expired, the user is redirected to the proper page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything first before asking? Got any code examples? What 'loads of errors' do you refer too?

Comment: Sounds like you need to implement some basic error handling.

Comment: @Randall in fact, not actually errors but notices that the session variable is not defined, but those are false positives due to what I mentioned in the OP

Comment: *"if you close the browser and then open again, the first thing the app does is to open that webpage again"* - Chrome doesn't do that on my mobile device, it goes back to its default. Are you sure you're actually closing the app and not just leaving it running in the background when you switch to something else?

Comment: @nnnnnn browse to wikipedia for example, then exit the app and swipe close chrome (if using android), then open chrome again, and the first thing chrome will do is load wikipedia, at least that's what it does with mine.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a library like [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors), you can handle errors caused by your invalid session with interceptors and trigger a page reload programmatically.

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
  return response;
}, function(error) (
  if(error.statusCode === 401)
    window.location.reload(); //or whatever
  return error;
});
```

Comment: This is not what I'm asking for, my application has error handling already